# FileReader onload callback

Tags: javascript, image, callback, onload

my main goal is to return false out of _validateFile if a File (that is a jpeg) does not have the minimum dimensions. The issue I am having is that it looks like code underneath is getting hit and I can't return false out of _validateFile. I think I have to use a closure but I am not sure. Here is some code:

```
_validateFile: function(file){

var validDim = 1;

this._helper(file, function(x,y){
    if(x < 682 || y < 459){
        validDim = 2;
    } else{
        validDim = 3;
    }
});

    if(validDim == 2) return false;
    else if(validDim == 3) return true;
    return true;

},

 _helper: function(file, callback){

    var fr = new FileReader;

fr.onload = function() {
    var img = new Image;

    img.onload = function(){
                var x = img.width;
                var y = img.height;
                callback(x,y);
            }

    img.src = fr.result;
};
fr.readAsDataURL(file);
},
```

Any pointers in the right direction are greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you missing '()' to invoke a constructor

```
var fr  = new FileReader();
var img = new Image();
```

Could you give some detail code about the way you use this object method (_validateFile)?